# Interacting with spark installed on WSL from jupyter notebook installed in windows, is that actually possible?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, jupyter

i have spark installed on my WSL ubuntu dist and i want to interact with it using jupyter notebook that is installed with anaconda on my windows machine is that possible